# In the non-linear animation window, what do these button do?

Tags: animation, actions

I'm confused what these button do. When none of the boxes of the actions are checked, the character is in rest position. If I check the box of the idle track (NlaTrack.001) and play it, idle animation works fine. I uncheck that and do that for the KnightRun and that also works fine. But if I uncheck the KnightRun and check the Idle, the last position of the knight run merges with the position of the Idle. That also happens for the star button. I'm getting frustrated cause I have to re-edit the pose over and over again. I want to know how to play tracks individually.

[image]

[image: Last position of the knight run]

[image: Idle position]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, if you put a track over another one, the strip that is playing on this track will play over the strips of the tracks that lay under. But you can choose to combine the strips with the settings you'll find in the *N panel > Strip* tab:

[image]

*Extrapolation* will allow you to determine if the action of the strip is supposed to go on after it ends or let the other ones underneath play. *Blending* will allow you to determine if the keyframes blend and how they blend.

I hope it answers?

Comment: Thank you so much, saved me so much grief :'>